# Aligning '=' on protocol buffers .proto files

Tags: protocol-buffers

Should the equals sign be alined on protocol buffers? I am having a huge discussion with a colleague and we can't get to decide on what's the best practice.

```
message foobar {
    optional bool var_one_short             = 1;
    optional bool var_two_looooooooong_name = 2;
    optional bool another_var               = 3;
}
```

vs

```
message foobar {
    optional bool var_one_short = 1;
    optional bool var_two_looooooooong_name = 2;
    optional bool another_var = 3;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting data, not code (although code can be generated *from* a .proto file, the .proto file itself doesn't contain any code).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I had completely forgot about this question if it wasn't for the notification. This question was originally migrated from SO to here. I don't want to seem protective but I actually disagree, protobufs defines a schema, so I would argue that schemas are subject to codereview.

Comment: You raise a fair argument, *but* the long and short of it is that you need to draw a line somewhere. IMO, the line is drawn at languages that let you specify *actions* to be taken. Yes, actions such as reading and writing are implied with protobufs, but they're still strictly implicit, not embodied in the code itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the second version is much easier to maintain. If you have a new variable with a longer name (like `var_two_reaalllllly_looooooooong_name`) you don't have to modify three other lines too to keep it nice. The first version also could cause unnecessary patch/merge conflicts.

From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition* by *Steve McConnell*, p758:

> **Do not align right sides of assignment statements**
>
> [...]
>
> With the benefit of 10 years’ hindsight, I have found that, 
>   while this indentation style might look attractive, it becomes
>   a headache to maintain the alignment of the equals signs as variable 
>   names change and code is run through tools that substitute tabs
>   for spaces and spaces for tabs. It is also hard to maintain as
>   lines are moved among different parts of the program that have 
>   different levels of indentation.

Comment: I think it's important to note that a lot of modern editors support this (example: [Sublime Text 2](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment)), so maintenance becomes trivial.

Comment: I use sublime and yes it makes it easier. But his opinion convinced me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple "Readability vs Maintainability" issue. In a case like this, choose the second one. So, if you change your code or add a new variable, you don't have to realign the code at the end. You can achieve readability with other ways like giving your variables good names.

Answer (score 1):

I like more the first solution because it visually groups together the variables on the left side of the `=` and the value on the right side.
Unfortunately I can't back this preference with a strong reason other than personal taste.

In your situation I'd struggle for uniformity across your codebase and define a single convention that every programmer should follow.
It seems that you and your colleague are already trying to agree, but I wanted to point it out explicitly because I think that it is very important.